# jQuery datetimepicker formatting in rails 3.2

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, datetimepicker

I'm using the following datetimepicker which from my understanding is the jquery-ui datepicker that has been extended.

http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

My issue is I want to display to the user am and pm times, but I want to format it differently so that when I submit it to a mysql database, the time format enters the standard "YY-mm-dd - hh:mm:ss" format.

This is the format that it currently inputs

[image: Format of time]

Comment: I like the idea, it sounds pragmatic and pratical. Can we see what you've tried so far?

Comment: i think you could change the format of the date before you save it into the database i.e formatting it with rails

Comment: @fuzionpro that's definitely true, you could also handle the logic with javascript as well. I'd like to see OP's efforts so we can guide him along. CNP scripts don't help anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For people with the same issue as the above, I received some good advice from the developer of the above plugin that the responsibility for formatting should belong in the middleware (ruby, php, python, etc).  So after doing some searching I found the following gem and added to my Gemfile.

```
gem 'validates_timeliness'
```

This plugin relies on the timeliness gem and has many built in functions that accepts many different formats out of the box.

Add this to your model and you're done:

```
validates_datetime :date_paid_on, :allow_blank => true
```

You may run into the scenario where you may need a custom parser.  If so just add the following to your validates_timeliness.rb initializer.

```
config.parser.add_formats(:datetime, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:nn:ss tz')
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI date pickers support passing `altField` and `altFormat` options to them for exactly this purpose.  The plugin you are using also supports extending that (although in a confusing way).  I believe this is the correct level of options that will get you what you need. [Try it out live here](http://jsfiddle.net/japanick/TSRs8/)

Assuming a form with these elements:

```
<input type="text" id="datetime" />
<input type="hidden" id="datetime_to_server" name="formatted_date_time" />
```

You can then set up your datetimepicker widget like this:

```
$('#datetime').datetimepicker( 
  { altField  : '#datetime_to_server',  // selector of the hidden input field you want sent to the server
    altFormat : 'yy-m-d',
    altFieldTimeOnly : false,
    altTimeFormat : 'hh:mm:00' } );
```

Comment: I've confirmed that for some reason I can get the altfield working with the normal ui datepicker, but can't get it to format with the datetimepicker.

Comment: Did you click on the jsfiddle link I provided in my post? Click on the "Try it out live here" link. Isn't it working as you wanted?  Note you specified the server-side expected hh:mm:ss, but the datetimepicker doesn't have seconds, so that's why I put "00" in the formatter. ampm shouldn't be needed in the formatter since you wanted hh:mm:ss (so, 1pm will be sent as 13:00:00). Let me know if I can help any further..

Comment: upgrading to the latest version of the datetimepicker helped, although there seems to be a documented bug with the behavior that when you have a pm time selected for ex "2012-10-15 03:15pm", the altTimeFormat seems to want to convert it to "2012-10-15 03:15:00"  so it completely fouls the conversion back to 24 hour time. https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon/issues/211#issuecomment-9495944