# text form field, date column in db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The code below is taken from Ryan Bates' revised episode on making calendars in Rails apps. http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars-revised?view=asciicast If you're not familiar with his episode format, he publishes the "before" and "after" source code for the projects he makes. While implementing the jquery datepicker in the episode, he changes the `<%= f.date_select :published_on %>` field to a `<%= f.text_field :published_on %>`, which I guess is a requirement of the jQuery datepicker. However, looking at the schema for the "after" code, the `published_on` column remains a "date" column, rather than a "text" field. That seems odd since the form field becomes text field, or is that the "recommended" way to do it?  Please provide some guidance as to what the db column should be if the form field is a text_field for a date.

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :published_on %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :published_on %>
  </div>


ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120810222509) do

  create_table "articles", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "published_on"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use jQuery Datepicker all the time and use text_field in the form and the model attribute as a date_field.  It works.  Rails will automatically parse the value in the correct format.  If you have any issues with it saving correctly to the database, you can specify a format with jQuery Datepicker.

There are also gems that validate the date format of a text_field.  I ran into a scenario where I was also using a time picker.  This scenario did throw off the default date parse built into rails.  Here is a link to the question I asked on Stack O

[jQuery datetimepicker formatting in rails 3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907816/jquery-datetimepicker-formatting-in-rails-3-2)

The date_field helper provided by rails, will concatenate the values of the three drop down selects into a string,  with a text field, the date picker does the work for you.